# Retorno LINQ com valores repetidos

Tags: c#, query, mvc, linq

Estou com problemas em uma consulta dentro da minha aplicação. Os valores retornados pela minha consulta estão repetidos, o mesmo valor aparece 407 vezes, quando  o certo teria que ser 407 registro diferente, assim como está no banco de dados.
Tentei realizar a consulta de duas formas diferentes:

```
List<TBZFI2_APENAS_DRE> Zfi2 = db.TBZFI2_APENAS_DRE.Where(x => x.TBCLASSECUSTO.TBSUBMETRICA_CLASSE.Any(y => y.Id_SubMetrica == itens.Id_SubMetrica) && x.mes == mesInicial && x.ano == tbplanejamento.Ano).ToList();
```

e também dessa maneira:

```
string query1 = string.Format("SELECT * FROM TBZFI2_APENAS_DRE ZFI2 JOIN TBCLASSECUSTO CC ON CC.Id = ZFI2.Id_Classe JOIN TBSUBMETRICA_CLASSE SC ON SC.Id_Classe = CC.Id JOIN TBSUBMETRICA SUBMETR ON SC.Id_SubMetrica = SUBMETR.Id WHERE ZFI2.ano = {0} AND SUBMETR.Id = {1} and ZFI2.mes = {2}", tbplanejamento.Ano, itens.Id_SubMetrica, mesInicial);
            var ClassesPareto = db.TBZFI2_APENAS_DRE.SqlQuery(query1);
```

Ambas as formas me retornam um resultado de 407 registros repetidos. 
Debbugando a aplicação, peguei a query montada que a segunda forma listada acima gera. A query foi a seguinte:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TBZFI2_APENAS_DRE ZFI2 
   JOIN TBCLASSECUSTO CC ON CC.Id = ZFI2.Id_Classe 
   JOIN TBSUBMETRICA_CLASSE SC ON SC.Id_Classe = CC.Id 
   JOIN TBSUBMETRICA SUBMETR ON SC.Id_SubMetrica = SUBMETR.Id 
WHERE ZFI2.ano = 2019 
AND SUBMETR.Id = 24 
and ZFI2.mes = 1
```

Como podemos ver, os parametros que passei na query funcionaram direitinho, peguei essa mesma query montada e joguei direto no SQL Server e o resultado foi o correto.
Tive  um retorno de 407 registros, cada um com seu respectivo valor.

Conclusão: A mesma query quando executada pela aplicação retorna uma lista de todos os registros repetidos e quando gerada pelo banco retorna os registros corretos. Já tentei de tudo e não consegui um resultado satisfatório. Gostaria da ajuda de vocês para resolver esse caso.

Comment: Verifique se a chave primária da tabela está mapeado corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia! Passei pelo mesmo problema. No meu caso, eu tinha um model de uma view e estava setando a KEY do model no campo que poderia se repetir.
Antes:

```
[Table("vw_PerfilUsuarioArea")]
public class PerfilUsuarioArea
{
    [Key]
    public short Status { get; set; }
    public string IdUsuario { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Perfil { get; set; }
    public string EmailUsers { get; set; }
    public Guid IdArea { get; set; }
    public string Sigla { get; set; }
    public string EmailArea { get; set; }
}
```

Depois:

```
[Table("vw_PerfilUsuarioArea")]
public class PerfilUsuarioArea
{
    [Key]
    public string IdUsuario { get; set; }
    public short Status { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Perfil { get; set; }
    public string EmailUsers { get; set; }
    public Guid IdArea { get; set; }
    public string Sigla { get; set; }
    public string EmailArea { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).